# Minifying javascript that contains server-side tags

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm already using bundling and minification but there are some javascript code in each page that they also contain server-side `<% %>` tags. I tried online javascript compressors but they just remove these tags and everything inside them. 
Is there a way to this?

sample code:

```
    if('<%=id%>'=='0'){
                    $.get('/ajax/getnameinfo.aspx?l=<%=Settings.LanguageID%>&n=' + $('#name').val(), function (d) {
                        $('.wait').remove();
                        var a = $(d).children().first();
                        if (a.length == 0) {
       }                     $('form').submit();
    });
}
```

Comment: Ideally: 1. Don't create things like that in new pages. 2. In any existing pages, rip out the logic into a function that accepts arguments in a separate `.js` file, and replace the logic in the page with just a call to that function. Then, bundle and minify the `.js` files. (In the course of this, avoid creating multiple globals; you only need one, at most: An object with the various functions as properties.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this somewhere on your generated page:

```
window._server = {id: '<%=id%>', languageId: '<%=Settings.LanguageID%>'};
```

and modify JS into:

```
if(_server.id=='0'){
                $.get('/ajax/getnameinfo.aspx?l='+_server.languageId+'&n=' + $('#name').val(), function (d) {
                    $('.wait').remove();
                    var a = $(d).children().first();
                    if (a.length == 0) {
   }                     $('form').submit();
});
```

You can replace _server with any variable that's explicitly bound to js file. You may additionally consider using external data source (an object passed to a constructor) in case you want to use your javascript with both asp-driven and js-driven parameters.